# Roblox studio - How do I change a TextLabel text by script

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to change a TextLabel's text.

I have this simple script:

local text = script.Parent.Text

wait(2)

text = "Hey, there!"

But when I play it, the Text just stays to the default label. - no error or warning

Comment: Also I tried both local and normal script, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the `Text` property into a variable, you are simply holding a snapshot of the text string at that moment in time. Updating the variable does not also update the TextLabel. You must explicitly set the [Text](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TextLabel#Text) property to update it.

So, in a LocalScript, try this :

```lua
local textLabel = script.Parent

wait(2)

textLabel.Text = "Hey, there!"
```